How to call blocking IO calls on Mono
I have utility methods look like this.
    public static WebClient.ResponseSpec retrieve(final String baseUrl, final Duration responseTimeout) {
        // ...
    }

    public static <T> Flux<T> retrieveBodyToFlux(final String baseUrl, final Duration responseTimeout,
                                                 final Class<T> elementClass) {
        return retrieve(baseUrl, responseTimeout)
                .bodyToFlux(elementClass);
    }

    public static Mono<Void> download(final String baseUrl, final Duration responseTimeout,
                                      final Path destination, final OpenOption... openOptions) {
        return DataBufferUtils.write(
                retrieveBodyToFlux(baseUrl, responseTimeout, DataBuffer.class),
                destination,
                openOptions
        );
    }

Now I want to add another method for client to consume a temporary file.
    // Let me download the file, and you can just cononsume the file!
    public static Mono<Void> download(final String baseUrl, final Duration responseTimeout,
                                      final Consumer<? super Path> consumer) {

        // Create a temp file
        // download the URL to the file
        // accept the file to the consumer; possibly blocking IO operations
        // don't forget to delete the file!
    }

How can I do the job without any blocking call warning?
I tried (, and it seems to work), but I'm wondering what am I doing. Is it optimal? Do I have other ways?
        return Mono.usingWhen(
                        Mono.fromCallable(() -> Files.createTempFile(null, null)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()),
                        p -> download(baseUrl, responseTimeout, p, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
                                .then(Mono.just(p))
                                .doOnNext(consumer).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()),
                        p -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                            Files.delete(p);
                            return null;
                        }).publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).then()
                )
                .then();


example code snippet seems like already best practice.
and provide  another code snippet for  reference;


Mono.usingWhen(
        // Resource acquisition
        Mono.fromCallable(() -> Files.createTempFile(null, null)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()),
        
        // Resource usage
        tempFile -> download(baseUrl, responseTimeout, tempFile, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
                    .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> consumer.accept(tempFile)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())),
        
        // Resource cleanup
        tempFile -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            try {
                Files.delete(tempFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
).then();


